# How to execute a CP only when the value is changed for the first time?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm writing a small validation component that displays an error message if the value is blank/emtpy.

I'm in a bit of a tricky situation.

The parent template:

```
  {{#validation-wrapper isNew=model.isNew value=model.name presence=true minimum=5}}
    {{input value=model.name}}
  {{/validation-wrapper}}
```

The component's computed property:

```
  isPresenceValid: Ember.computed('value', {
    get() {
      return Ember.isPresent(this.get('value'));
    }
  }),
```

The component template:

```
{{#if hasErrors}}
  <div class="errors animated bounceIn">
    {{#if presence}}
      <p class="{{if isPresenceValid '-green' '-red'}}"><i class="fa {{if isPresenceValid 'fa-check' 'fa-close'}}"> Must be present</i></p>
    {{/if}}

    {{#if minimum}}
      <p class="{{if isMinimumValid '-green' '-red'}}"><i class="fa  {{if isMinimumValid 'fa-check' 'fa-close'}}"> Must be less than {{minimum}}</i></p>
    {{/if}}
  </div>
{{/if}}

{{yield}}
```

On page load. `value` will always be blank. Which means this CP will return `false`, triggering the template to display an error.

I only want this CP to execute if the `value` was changed at any point.

Which also means. On page load, if `value` is blank. Don't display any errors. However, if the user types a value and then removes it. Thats the time the CP executes (returns `false`).

Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you want the field to be always valid if it is the same as its initial value. So, we just need to save it on init time and compare it to the current value. `shouldValidate` acts like a toggle to let us know if the value has changed. Example component:

```
//app/components/base-validation-component.js
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  didInitAttrs() {
    this.set('initialValue', this.get('value'));
  }

  shouldValidate: Ember.computed('value', 'initialValue', function() {
    return this.get('value') !== this.get('initialValue');
  }),

  isValid: Ember.computed('shouldValidate', 'value', {
    return this.get('shouldValidate') ? this.validate(this.get('value')) : true;
  }),

  validate(value) {
    return Ember.isPresent(value);
  }

})
```

I also abstracted away the `validate(value)` method. This way you can subclass this component and just override that method, preserving all of this initial value logic. Example:

```
//app/components/positive-validation-component.js
export default BaseValidationComponent.extend({
  validate(value) {
    return value > 0;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using the latest ember you could try something like this in your component template:

```
<input value='{{value}}' oninput='{{action 'validate' value='target.value'}}'>
```

Then in your component:

```
actions: {
  validate(value) {
    const isValid = Ember.isPresent(value);
    this.setProperties({valid, value});
  }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which part of the implementation requires the latest version of ember?

Comment: I think adding the action to `oninput` require at lease 1.13

Comment: I made an edit to include the template so you get the gist on the structure. Was hoping to do this kind of validation handling outside of an action. Possibly using computed properties and if the last resort, observers.